# CSS-Compile does not work in pydio / ajaXplorer

Tags: html, css, ajax, compilation, pydio

I’m using pydio 5.2.2 and I’m trying to the the theme-css – unsuccessfully.

1. I set AJXP_CLIENT_DEBUG to true,
2. edited the css-files listed in allz_list.txt -> everything looks fine.
3. Then I call myPydioUrl.com/?compile=true – it loads a while and no errors come up.
4. When I set 1. to false again or call ?skipDebug=true my changes are gone (they are still in the uncompiled css-files, but not in the compiled allz.css)

Currently I’m running the site with debug-mode set to true, but I like to change that soon.
Any ideas, what could cause this behavior? Or any hint, where I could find an error log? The standard apache-logs aren’t showing any error.

Additionally, when I share a document via pydio and call it via myPydioUrl.com/data/public/xxx.php, the page always calls the compiled css-file – even the the debug mode is set to true. Do I have to set an extra option for that kind of page?

Thanks for any hint!
ago

Comment: It's solved!
It was an user/group issue, the webserver wasn't allowed to write the allz.css file. Now its working fine!